# How to simulate multiple consecutive transactions and get the resulting state?

Tags: web3js, transactions, contract-invocation, testing

I'm trying to simulate a transaction on the public blockchain that invokes a contract's method with certain parameters. Then I want to make a follow-up transaction with some other method call.

I figured that I can use `call()` function in the JavaScript console to invoke a method without actually publishing a real transaction, e.g:

```
var abi = [...];
var contractAddress = "0x...";
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
contract.updateSomething.call(...);    // change some values
```

The problem now is: How can I make another call that uses the updated state of the contract?

If I just use another `call()` it returns the old value, not the updated one.

```
...
contract.updateSomething.call(...);    // change some values
contract.readSomething.call();         // returns old value
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the transaction is mined. One way to accomplish that is to make the method `updateSomethig` to generate an event, and to make your program listen such events. When the transactions is mined an event will be generated, and your callback will be called.